How does the wall-phasing speedrun glitch work in Mega Man 2?
I watched Shinryuu's tool-assisted speedrun of Mega Man 2 (NES) and noticed an interesting glitch that occurs multiple times throughout the run. I'm curious about how it works and hope someone can explain its mechanics.
The glitch first appears at 02:53 in the video. In Heat Man's stage, Mega Man uses the Item-3 platform to ascend to the top of the screen, where he somehow glitches into the wall/blocks. Once inside, he moves forward at an increased speed until reaching the end of the wall/block section.

A similar technique is employed in Air Man's stage at 05:50 in the video, this time using the Item-1 platform just before entering the area before the boss room.

From what I can tell, it looks like Mega Man positions himself on the rightmost edge of the platform, just before he would normally fall off. He rises up to the wall or block at the top, then somehow glitches through it and jumps, resulting in faster forward movement until the wall or block ends.
Is my understanding of this technique correct? How exactly does Mega Man enter the wall/blocks to trigger the glitch, and what button inputs are required to pull it off?

There are no special inputs needed. You just need Item one, which you get from beating Heat Man. And then you have to position yourself correctly.
When you are too far under the ceiling, Item one will just disappear and you will drop down:

If you are too far away, you will be moved next to the ceiling automatically:


But when you hit it perfectly, you will be clipped into and rushed all across the ceiling:

